# Работа с кнопками в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

У меня есть страничка с 2-я таблицами, между этими таблицами нужно сделать 2 кнопки, которые будут располагаться во всю высоту таблиц.
Я добавил 2 кнопки следующим образом:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active panel panel-primary" id="questionintopik">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Таблица №1 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
                                <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
                                <input id="search-avaliable">
                                <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
                                <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $LeftItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
                            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Кнопки -->
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                            <a id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success">&gt;&gt;</a><br>
                            <a id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger">&lt;&lt;</a>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Таблица №2 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
                                <h4>Вопросы входящие в эту тему</h4>
                                <input id="search-assigned"><br>
                                <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $RightItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
                            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

[image: Фото]

**Минимальный рабочий код:**

```
        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#btn-add', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selected = $(document).find('#first option:selected');
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selected.appendTo('#second');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#btn-remove', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selected = $(document).find('#second option:selected');
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    selected.appendTo('#first');
                }
            });
        });
<html>
    <select name="first" id="first" size="20" style="width: 100px;" multiple>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
<br>
      <a id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success"  >&gt;&gt;</a>
      <br>
      <a id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger">&lt;&lt;</a>
<br>
    <select 

name="second" id="second" size="20" style="width: 100px;" multiple>
    </select>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Попробуй у кнопок написать style="height:50%;"

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Высота в процентах будет работать только если родительский див с явно заданной высотой либо когда дочерний абсолютно позиционирован.

1 - можете поставить кнопки вовнутрь первой колонки и абсолютно позиционировать их относительно высоты самой колонки.

2 - можете переверстать колонки из блоков во флексы, грид или таблицы, тогда можно будет растянуть кнопки на высоту колонки.

*P.S. Если хотите конкретного ответа - показывайте полный код, с воспроизвоидмым примером.*

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос и указал весь код, так же прикрепил фото как это выглядит. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: код не воспоризвести - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ну вот сделал минимальный код который свободно запускается и работает. добавил снизу в вопрос.